# How can I run the netty DiscardServer and netty DiscardClient in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, netty

I want to know how I can compile and run the netty DiscardServer and netty DiscardClient example in intelliJ IDEA. I can compile and run both the server and client from the command line (in Ubuntu/linux), using two terminals but I am unable to compile and run it in IntelliJ IDEA. I am using the latest stable version which is 4.0.33 (http://dl.bintray.com/netty/downloads/netty-4.0.33.Final.tar.bz2).

### Compiling and running Discard server From the command line:

1. I extracted the contents of the netty-all-4.0.33.Final-sources.jar
2. Compiled the DiscardServer.java class:
   javac -cp .:netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer.java
3. Executed/Ran the DiscardServer
   java -cp .:netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer

Note: since the netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar contains the DiscardServer.class file I also can just extract contents of the jar file and run
java -cp .:netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer

but I would like to modify the discardServer class

### Steps I took to Compile and Run code in IntelliJ IDEA.

1. I extracted the contents of the netty-all-4.0.33.Final-sources.jar
2. Imported Project from external source: made netty my root source directory, but by doing this it didn't recognize the subdirectories as individual modules, so when editing the run confiuration I was only able to specify one main class. In addition, since the netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar wasn't put in the lib directory as a sub-directory under the netty root directory it didn't recognize any libraries

What I did after this.
1. I extracted the contents of the netty-all-4.0.33.Final-sources.jar
2. Copied thethe Example/discard directory to a separated directory I named ServerClientExample. I made subdirectories: client and server with the server and client source code placed in it's respective directories.  This was done, so when I import the source code in IntelliJ IDEA, it will recognize the 2 sub-directories as 2 different modules.  However doing it this way also requires me to change the package name of each source file, since the original package was specified as follows. io.netty.example.discard. I also added a lib sub-directory to the ServerClientExample containing the netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar so IntelliJ IDEA can pick up the external library (jar file) necessary to compile and run the server and client.  This didn't work.

Thank you for your response

Comment: Does the project have a pom? If it's not in the sources, checkout the github repo. If you can't find a pom, or a build.gradle file, then you should consider the project to be broken, and you should move on.